# Can I say "I want to make something useful, to more people the better."

Tags: grammar, idioms

1. I want to make something useful, to more people the better.
2. Or. I want to make something useful. To more people, the better.

I not sure how this sounds to a native English speaker. There are a lot of things that aren't grammatical but still widely used because they have been used so often that they are now idiomatic.

I have always heard people say "I want to help people, the more the better." Something like that. The more people to whom my product is useful, the better. I am pretty sure this last sentence is grammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that your last sentence is good grammatically.

> I want to help people, the more the better.

The comma in that sentence is acceptable, so would be a colon. The second, [subordinate, clause](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateclause.htm) is an idiomatic expression. The form of this idiom is always ***"The [X] the better"***, where [X] is a [comparative adjective](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/grammar/partsofspeech/adjectives/comparatives.shtml). A native speaker/writer might even use the expression [as a sentence on it's own](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic14885.html) in some contexts, for added emphasis, perhaps with a comma. For example:

> I crave grammar questions. The more, the better!

However, there are various problems with your examples **1.** and **2.** Say them and you'll be understood, but you'll sound like a non-fluent learner.

**"... to more people the better."** is just wrong - it's not a known English idiom. **"... to the more people the better"** is good. I wouldn't be surprised to hear it from an educated native speaker, but it sounds like a specifically British middle/upper class phrasing to me. A more international usage would be...

> I want to make something useful to people: the more the better.

For top marks, though, you should use...

> **I want to make something useful to people, the more the *merrier*.**

... this is because if you use *better*, it's not completely clear that you mean more **people** (finding it useful) is better, rather than more **usefulness** being better! ["The more the merrier"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more-the-merrier) is a common idiom used to say that a bigger **group of people** is desirable.

... Gosh, what a long answer already to a short question! :)